# Query getResultList return duplicate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have encountered a problem when using `Query.getResultList()` returning duplicate data. I also did some research and found that we need to `setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`. It worked fine.

However, this method is deprecated in hibernate 5.2, and we're using hibernate 5.2.8, so are there any alternate way to do this?

Update 1: I was using HQL. The query look like this:
`select u from UserEntity u left join fetch u.profile p left join fetch p.roles r left join fetch r.roleFunction`

Comment: what is your query? is it a `CriteriaQuery`? what about using distinct select?

Comment: I just update my question, thanks for asking

Comment: does `select distinct u from UserEntity u left join fetch u.profile p left join fetch p.roles r left join fetch r.roleFunction` work?

Comment: Please update your question with your whole code, including the `Query`definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use typedquery instead of questions. In latest hibernate, typed query provides many options to getresultlist or getsingleresult...